# Getting error while calculating NDCG using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ranking

I'm trying to calculate the NDCG score for binary relevances:

```
from sklearn import metrics

y_true = [[3]]
y_score = [[5]]
metrics.ndcg_score(y_true, y_score)
```

And getting error

```
ValueError: Only ('multilabel-indicator', 'continuous-multioutput', 'multiclass-multioutput') formats are supported. Got binary instead
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to obtain such metrics which include ranking (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score.html)) for *single* true-predicted pairs does not make any sense (although admittedly the error message is not very informative here); you need at least two pairs:

```
y_true = [[3,3]]
y_score = [[5, 5]]
metrics.ndcg_score(y_true, y_score)
# 0.9999999999999998
```